# how to find a string in a list of folders from a find command

Tags: linux, find

i want to find a string in some folders, and that list of folders is from a find command,
1, use find command to find a list of folders,
2, find a certain string in that list of folders,

how to do that ?

the following do not work,

```
find / - name "ETL" | grep -r "BHIF_VIEW"
```

Comment: Have you tried googling this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`find`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html) with `-exec` like so:

```
find / - name "ETL" -exec grep -r "BHIF_VIEW" {} \;
```